# chrome.sockets.udp how to successfully broadcast?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools

I'm attempting to build an Ionic app that would interact with other apps on the same wifi network.  So, I'm looking to chrome.sockets.udp to establish some way to send messages between them.  Below is my first attempt as sending a message to all devices on the same network - although this example is just on one host.  I have both `setBroadcast` and `setMulticastLoopbackMode` set to true, but a message is never received in one of the listeners.  Why not?

```
let chrome = window['chrome'];

chrome.sockets.udp.onReceiveError.addListener((data) => {
    console.log('received error');
    console.log(data);
});

chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener((data) => {
    console.log('received');
    console.log(data);
});

chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, (socketInfo) => {
    // The socket is created, now we can send some data

    var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
    console.log(socketId);

chrome.sockets.udp.setBroadcast(socketId, true, (response_code) => {
        console.log('broadcast: ' + response_code);
        chrome.sockets.udp.setMulticastLoopbackMode(socketId, true, (loopback_code) => {
            console.log('loopback code: ' + loopback_code);
            chrome.sockets.udp.bind(socketId, '0.0.0.0', 0, (bind_code) => {
                console.log('bind: ' + bind_code);
                chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, str2ab('123'), '255.255.255.0', 10090, (sendInfo) => {
                    console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
                    console.log("sent_code " + sendInfo.resultCode);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Output:

```
[17:49:30]  console.log: 2
[17:49:30]  console.log: broadcast: 0
[17:49:30]  console.log: loopback code: 0
[17:49:30]  console.log: bind: 0
[17:49:30]  console.log: sent 6
[17:49:30]  console.log: sent_code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a loop and send the udp packet ip by ip. You can see the example below.

```
  chrome.sockets.udp.bind(socketId, '0.0.0.0', 1234, (bind_code) => {
    console.log('bind: ' + bind_code);

    for (var i = 1; i < 254; i++) {
      chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, this.str2ab('123'), '192.168.1.' + i, 1234, (sendInfo) => { console.log(sendInfo) });
    }

  });
```

Here 192.168.1.1 is the Gateway IP.